# Leer cadena de conexión que se encuentra en un archivo .txt

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy usando OleDb para crear la conexión a la BD local, pero quiero poder guardar dicha cadena de conexión en un archivo .txt

```
OleDbCon.ConnectionString = new string[] { "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=E:\\MYDB;" };
```

por ahora el path de la cadena de conexión es: E:\MYDB. Como puedo leer esa cadena desde un archivo .txt en el campo "Source"?

Comment: ¿Por qué no mejor creas un archivo de configuración? https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms243192.aspx

Comment: porque ese .txt va a ser editado desde otro programa.

Comment: Puedes agregar mas info a tu pregunta? Que version de .NET, que tipo de entorno (web, winform, servicio, consola, wpf, etc). Ademas dale una mirada antes a "archivos de configuración en .net" a ver si puedes comenzar a utilizarlos y preguntar exactametnte. Incluso en los archivos de configuración hay una secciones especial para ConnectionStrings... pero lo primordial, y dependiendo del tipo de entorno, es *resguardar dicha info* para que no la pueden leer incluso si tiene acceso a dicho archivo. Ya que es una información sensible

Comment: claro, estoy haciendo un servicio WCF que va a insertar información en unas tablas locales.

Comment: @JoseSebastianRicoLeyton **[edit] la pregunta** con mas detalles. Si necesitas guardar la cadena de conexión en un archivo .txt, te sugiero agregar un ejemplo del contenido del archivo de texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
string _dataSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\MYDB");
OleDbCon.ConnectionString = new string[] { "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + _dataSource };
```

De esta manera puedes editar el archivo ubicado en E:\MYDB